# Android: Seperate Bluetooth Classic Scan from Low Energy Scan, or distinguish Classic Devices from Low Energy Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.4-kitkat, connectivity

I'm developing an android app, that implements Bluetooth.
Bluetooth Scan and everything runs fine (i refered to the android bletooth chat code example here:(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat ), but when the bluetooth scan runs, my device finds also Bluetooth Low Energy devices.
I've tried it with a Galaxy Nexus (Android KitKat) and with a Nexus 7 (2013) (also KitKat).

How can I prevent the BluetoothAdapter from discovering Bluetooth LE Devices, when using the function

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

The official Bluetooth Low Energy example (http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html) says that for an Low energy scan you have to use

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startLEScan();
```

As an workaround is it possible to distinguish a discovered Bluetooth Classic Device from a discovered Bluetooth Low Energy Device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function

```
getType()
```

for each

```
BluetoothDevice
```

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html

and search for all devices which are DEVICE_TYPE_CLASSIC